# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout

Tags: android, androidx

In my android app

gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in my main layout (nav_drawer_main):

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <include
            android:id="@+id/mainToolBar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="288dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:paddingLeft="16dip"
            android:paddingRight="16dip"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and here my tool bar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolBarConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbaTitleTextView"
                style="@style/textViewOneLine"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/application_name"
                app:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolBar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolBar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolBar" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

In Activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.nav_drawer_main);
```

But I get runtime exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390): Process: com.myproject, PID: 4390
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myproject/com.myproject.MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity_}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at com.myproject.MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity_.setContentView(MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity_.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at com.myproject.MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity.onCreate(MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at com.myproject.MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity_.onCreate(MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity_.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4390):    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your toolbar layout is of type `<layout>`, which is a special type used in conjunction with databinding. It requires also to have a `<data>` section for your binding classes. If you're not intending to use databinding, change your layout.

Answer (score 0):

**I think the problem in parent layout in tool_bar layout please change it to `<FramLayout>` and try again**

`<layout>` used with databinding. It requires also to have a  section for your binding classes. If you're not intending to use databinding

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBarConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbaTitleTextView"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/application_name"
            app:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolBar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolBar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```